# How to link one with another parts

Tags: java

I have this homework. I'm having a hard time linking the first part with the second. This is what I have. I know I'm missing something at some point to indicate that from the number input it should add the next 100 numbers.

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex216 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write a program in Java that reads an integer from the keyboard and makes the sum of the next 100 numbers, showing the result on screen


        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int =a
        int sum;
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
        a = myInput.nextInt();

        for (int n = a; n <= 100; n++)

            System.out.printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

This is what is casing me the trouble.

Comment: `int = a` is not valid java code.

Comment: not sure what logic you want either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all,`int =a` is not a valid expression. it should be `int a;` then as you want to add next `100` number from the given value, you need to add those values into sum, such as `sum = sum+number`.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    // correct declaration
    int a;
    // initialize sum with zero.
    int sum=0;
    System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
    a = myInput.nextInt();

    //for simplicity,start value n from a and loop until n reaches a+100.
    for (int n = a; n <= 100+a; n++) {
        sum = sum + n;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = "+ sum);
```